# Not started mysql

Tags: mysql

I get an error when I start mysql.

> [ERROR] [MY-012153] [InnoDB] Trying to access page number 262471942 in
> space 4294967279, space name innodb_undo_001, which is outside the
> tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get
> this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches
> the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.

Runs when `innodb_force_recovery = 5` in conf.

How do I fix this error? The backup is too old to restore. Can I delete the corrupted tabs?

p.s. in one table i have

> ERROR 1812 (HY000): Tablespace is missing for table `tokens`.

after send request `SELECT count(*) FROM tokens;`

Comment: I guess you could [drop the damaged undo tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-undo-tablespaces.html#truncate-undo-tablespace), but that won't give you your missing `tokens` table back.

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, this particular table I can sacrifice

Comment: @mustaccio i have `ERROR 1874 (HY000): Changes to undo tablespaces are not allowed in force_recovery mode`  or `ERROR 3604 (HY000): Storage engine can't drop table 'tokens'`